# Getting Values Outside a For Loop

Tags: apex, for

I am really struggling with getting some values I need outside a `for` loop.

```
public class Zenefits_Time_Off implements Schedulable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    public void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        Zenefits_Time_Off.makeCallout();
    }


    @future(callout = true)
    public static void makeCallout() {

        List<Time_Off_Request__c> torToUpdate = new List<Time_Off_Request__c> ();
        string url = 'xxxxx';
        system.debug('before while');
        while (url != null) {
            url = makeHttpCall(url, torToUpdate);
            system.debug('after while');
        }
        insert torToUpdate;
        system.debug('SECONDTOR ' + torToUpdate);
    }

    public static String makeHttpCall(String url, List<Time_Off_Request__c> torToUpdate) {
        string nextUrl = '';
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer xxxxx');
        request.setEndpoint(url);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) { 
            // Deserializes the JSON string into collections of posts.
            Map<String, Object> wrapper = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            if (wrapper.containsKey('data')) {
                Map<String, Object> wrapper2 = (Map<String, Object>) wrapper.get('data');
                if (wrapper2.containsKey('data')) {
                    nextUrl = (String) wrapper2.get('next_url');
                    system.debug('next URL' + nextUrl);
                    List<Object> vacationRequests = (List<Object>) wrapper2.get('data');
                    System.debug('Received the following vacation requests:');

                    Set<String> empIds = new Set<String>();

                    for (Object vacationRequestWrapper : vacationRequests) {
                        Map<String, Object> vacationRequest = (Map<String, Object>) vacationRequestWrapper;
                        if (vacationRequest.get('status').equals('approved')) {
                            Map<String, Object> wrapper3 = (Map<String, Object>) vacationRequest.get('creator');

                            string ptoUrl = (String) wrapper3.get('url');
                            string employeeId = ptoUrl.substring(ptoUrl.length() - 7, ptoUrl.length() - 0);
                            String Start_Date = (String) vacationRequest.get('start_date');
                            String End_Date = (String) vacationRequest.get('end_date');
                            string timeoff_ID = (String) vacationRequest.get('id');
                            string hours = (String) vacationRequest.get('hours');

                            empIds.add(employeeId);
                        }

                    }

                            List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Zenefits_ID__c FROM Contact WHERE Zenefits_ID__c IN: empIds LIMIT 200];
                            for (Contact con : contactList) {
                                System.debug('contactList ' + contactList); 

                                Time_Off_Request__c tor = new Time_Off_Request__c();
                                tor.Employee__c = con.Id;
                                tor.Project__c = 'a8q8A000000CafTQAS';
                                tor.First_Day_Off__c = date.newInstance(Start_Date);
                                tor.Last_Day_Off__c = date.newInstance(End_Date);
                                tor.Status__c = 'Saved';
                                tor.Zenefits_ID__c = timeoff_ID;
                                torToUpdate.add(TOR);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nextUrl;
    }
}
```

I need to get the values of `Start_Date`, `End_Date`, and `timeoff_ID`, so that I can use them in my record insert, but as you can see in the code those values are stuck up in the FOR loop.

How would I be able to get them outside the FOR loop so that they are able to be used in my value assignments such as:

```
tor.Last_Day_Off__c = date.newInstance(End_Date);
```

Comment: Are the dates in consideration here different for different `employeeId`? You may just like to use a `Map<Id, String>` here and be able to utilize that in your next loop to fetch the corresponding value.

Comment: The dates are associated with the employeeId, so how would I do that ? @JayantDas

Comment: Is `employeeId` same as the Contact's `Id` that you are iterating in your next loop?

Comment: it is not. EmployeeId is the Id associated with the system that we are pulling this information from, and we have each Salesforce users unique Id from that system in a field on their contact records (Zenefits_ID__C), so we are finding all the records where the EmployeeID matches with the Zenefits_ID__c and then inserting new records on the contacts in Salesforce based off of that. @JayantDas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, `employeeId` is basically your `Zenefits_ID__c` on your `Contact` record. So you will need to create a Map of the value associated with the `Zenefits_ID__c` and be able to utilize that later in your code.

A very basic implementation of this will look like as below (you should fine tune this, this is an approach to help you get started in that direction). Declare a `Map<String, String>` outside of the loops, populate it in your first loop and then use it in your second loop.

```
Map<String, String> mapVals = new Map<String, String>();
```

Then populate this in first loop as:

```
mapVals.put(employeeId, Start_Date);
```

And finally use the value of `Start_Date` in your second loop as:

```
tor.First_Day_Off__c = 
    date.newInstance(
        mapVals.get(con.Zenefits_ID__c));
```